# Dart: Explain SynchronousStreamController with an example

Tags: dart, controller, stream, synchronization, future

I have gone through the doc of [SynchronousStreamController](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.2/dart-async/SynchronousStreamController-class.html) manytimes.

I know that it delivers its events synchronously; events are fired immediately to the stream instead of adding to a later micro-task, causing extra latency.

But I still having hard-time comprehending the concept when I tried to illustrate the explanation of doc with a few examples of my own, however I failed. I get the same results for `StreamController(bool sync = false})` and `StreamController(bool sync = true})`.

Unfortunately, the doc does not present any examples other than explanation. Can someone help me by giving a simple working example that can show the difference when `sync` parameter is set `false` and `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronous stream controller delivers events when you call `add`, the asynchronous controller schedules a later event to deliver the event.
(Caveat: unless the stream subscription is paused, then they both delay delivery until it gets resumed.)

The difference can be seen from code like:

```dart
import "dart:async";
void main() async {
  var syncC = StreamController<int>(sync: true);
  var asyncC = StreamController<int>(); 
  syncC.stream.listen((e) { 
    print("Sync : $e");
  });
  asyncC.stream.listen((e) { 
    print("Async: $e");
  });
  print("Step 1");
  asyncC.add(37);
  print("Step 2");
  syncC.add(42); // Prints "Sync : 42" *right here*.
  print("Step 3");
  await Future.delayed(Duration.zero); // Prints "Async: 37" while waiting here.
  print("Step 4");
}
```

This code prints

```
Step 1
Step 2
Sync : 42
Step 3
Async: 37
Step 4
```

That shows that the synchronous controller event is received immediately when you call `add`. The asynchronous controller event is received in a later event (microtask to be precise.)

So, what does that mean, and when should you use a synchronous controller?

The answer to the latter is "Almost never, going on absolutely never."

Synchronous controllers exist as a primitive to allow people to write other streams manipulation libraries without introducing extra delays.
You should rarely be using a stream controller at all, preferring to use an `async*` method to create the stream.

If you are receiving events from something which is not a future or stream, you may need to convert that to a stream, and then a stream controller can be the thing you need.
In that case, if you are *absolutely certain* that you receive your incoming triggers as asynchronous events, it's OK to use a synchronous controller to emit an event at the same time.

It's *not* OK to call `add` on a synchronous controller in response to something getting called directly by user code. That includes in response to the stream being listened to (the `onListen` callback) or resumed (`onResume`).

A synchronous broadcast controller is extra dangerous to use, because it will throw if you try to add an event (calling `add`) while another event is being delivered. That can't happen for a single-subscription stream, because delivery happens atomically, and it won't matter for an async controller, because it'll just keep the event and deliver it later.

Use synchronous controllers with care. If in doubt, don't use them at all.

Answer (score 1):

See I take it like this, synchronous stream controller with `sync: true` ensures immediate event delivery upon addition to the stream. This is vital when maintaining precise event order and timing. And with `sync: false` does not guarantee immediate event processing; it queues events for later, possibly introducing slight delays.

Now an example:

```
import 'dart:async';

class EventBus {
  final _controller = StreamController<String>.broadcast(sync: true);

  Stream<String> get stream => _controller.stream;

  void publish(String event) {
    _controller.add(event);
  }
}

void main() {
  final eventBus = EventBus();

  eventBus.stream.listen((event) {
    print("Received event: $event");
  });

  eventBus.publish("Event 1");
  print("Event 1 published");

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    eventBus.publish("Event 2");
    print("Event 2 published");
  });

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    eventBus.publish("Event 3");
    print("Event 3 published");
  });
}
```

There's an EventBus class that uses a `SynchronousStreamController` (by setting `sync: true`) to broadcast events. This means events are delivered immediately when published.

And We're publishing three events with a slight delay between them.

Now When you run the code, we'll see that the events are received in the same order they were published because we're using a synchronous stream controller. If you were to replace `sync: true` with `sync: false` in the EventBus constructor, the events would be received out of order or with some delay due to the asynchronous behavior.

Comment: If you `add` an event before a listener, then `StreamController` acts as async even if the `sync` parameter is set to `true`. Correct me if I'm wrong?   In your example, when `eventBus.stream.listen((event) {print("Received event: $event");});` is after `eventBus.publish("Event 1");`, the output is the same as of `sync = false`

  eventBus.publish("Event 1");

Comment: Your example works with `add` method, but it cannot figure it out how to use it with `addStream` method. Can you please give an example with `addStream`?